# How to force dynamically allocated classes to have their members allocate on the heap as well?

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

Currently working on [cross-platform](/questions/tagged/cross-platform) allocation, where I am given a system, which has a very limited "stack" as an automatic scope for variables. However, said stack is still commonly used and filling up quickly. I was not allowed to increase the size, so I have to solve this programmatically.

---

Firstly, I have searched for similar questions, the most relevant being [this one](/questions/39048511/will-heap-allocated-objects-have-their-members-allocated-on-the-stack). However, there someone states that a member of a dynamically allocated class, will be allocated on the "heap", but those are apparently merely implementation details (So it might differ? Very confusing). Also, there is no clear answer to the issue. Reading the answers you'll still find yourself confused as to what member of a class is allocated where.

For simplicity, I am using a Linear Allocator, which allocates memory using a call to malloc and then offsets the pointer depending on the size of the class. Then creating/allocating the class, would be done with:

```
template<typename T> T* CreatePtr(size_t align)
{
    void *adr= Allocate(sizeof(T), align);

    return new(Adress) T();
}
```

So a class, which would be created using the above method, could be:

```
class A
{
    uint64_t size = 0u;
    bool foo = false;
    void *ptr = nullptr;
}
```

As I understand it, member `size` is allocated on the "heap", since `class A` was allocated using the LinearAllocated, which uses a `malloc` call, thus allocating the class on the "heap" implementation, which is decently large on my platform.

---

Now back to the question: is this the behavior above the correct one for Windows, Linux et cetera, meaning the variables are using the memory offset, since I pass the size with `sizeof(T)` to make sure it can hold its members (right?).

How would that work if you have a STL container, such as a vector. Would it allocate the vector on the "stack" implementation, since `sizeof(T)` cannot possibly know how big a dynamic container could be, even if you reserve space.

I dearly appreciate any suggestions, I hope I can clear this up. The title would hint towards the XY-problem, but I wrote it the way it is to stress the need to save memory.

Comment: A vector is guaranteed to use the free-space. It goes by a lot of names but in the comparison of stack vs heap it always lives on the "heap".

Comment: @SombreroChicken: that is not completely true; while the *contents* of the vector are stored on the heap, the metadata that describes where the contents are and how many elements are allocated and how many are actually used will be on the stack if you declare the vector on the stack.

Comment: `new` will use the heap on every platform I know of.  Unless you've checked and know for sure that it doesn't on a platform you care about, I would think it would be simpler, safer, and all around better to just use `new` (with appropriate smart pointers).

Comment: The default allocators for `STL` containers uses the heap (free store).

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes, I thought that part was clear as I was talking about it's contents, my bad.

Comment: I think you would have to write special code to get a member of a dynamic allocated object, (or its contents) to be stored on the stack. I should imagine it would be quite tricky.

Comment: A quick reminder: You need to do [a bit of extra voodoo](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to construct an `A` once you've granted it some space otherwise those default values will not be set.

Comment: @user4581301 Using placement new, I still have to write a constructor to initialize the members? Or did this change in c++11 and above?

Comment: The colloquial term “heap” just means “where `new` and friends put stuff”.  Don’t worry about its nature being an implementation detail.

Comment: @DavisHerring Not exactly, I had added the related question to this post, to highlight the difference. This question is mainly for figuring out the behavior and implementing the necessary calls to force heap allocation.

Comment: An object allocated in the heap will have all its members in the heap to. There is simply no language mechanism via which they could possibly be on the stack.

Comment: If you're worried about running out of stack space, the easy solution is to give your threads larger stacks.  Doing so will not increase your program's RAM usage, since under the OS's you mentioned, pages of RAM are not allocated unless/until they are actually used.